# MSDTC and firewall

Tags: firewall, msdtc

We are using MSDTC for SQL transactions.
I am having issue with setting up firewall for MSDTC to work.
The application and SQL are running on separate machine.
Currently MSDTC is working if i turn off firewall on application server.
I think there should be someway to add exception to the firewall setting for some ports.
So that firewall can still be ON and DTC will not have any issues.
I am not sure of the ports to add in firewall setting (I did try adding port 135 with no success)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have your Firewall allow port 135 and the dcom port range. By default, the dcom port range is 1024-65535. Thats a big range to open up. You can limit this range in the registry or using dcomcnfg. This post describes this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx

Comment: This answer is ancient and Microsoft now has a better way if you are using Windows Firewall. There are default rulesets for "Distributed Transaction Coordinator". You can enable those based on the "Domain" or "Public/Private" profiles. They include "RPC-EPMAP", "RPC", and "TCP-in".